# What can I do to speed up this bash script?

Tags: bash, time

The code I have goes through a file and multiplies all the numbers in the first column by a number. The code works, but I think its somewhat slow. It takes 26.676s (walltime) to go through a file with 2302 lines in it. I'm using a 2.7 GHz Intel Core i5 processor. Here is the code.

```
#!/bin/bash

i=2
sed -n 1p data.txt > data_diff.txt #outputs the header (x  y)
while [ $i -lt 2303 ]; do
    NUM=`sed -n "$i"p  data.txt | awk '{print $1}'`
    SEC=`sed -n "$i"p  data.txt | awk '{print $2}'`
    NNUM=$(bc <<< "$NUM*0.000123981")
    echo $NNUM $SEC >> data_diff.txt
    let i=$i+1
done
```

Comment: I was going to bet that searching for `bash while "don't do that"` would only bring up near-identical questions, but looks like some of the matches are about other topics.

Comment: Reading the entire input file again and again inside a loop is a huge antipattern. You should probably rewrite the whole thing a a single Awk script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Honestly, the biggest speedup you can get will come from using a single language that can do the whole task itself. This is mostly because your script invokes 5 extra processes for *each* line, and invoking extra processes is slow, but also text processing in bash is really not that well optimized.

I'd recommend awk, given that you have it available:

```
awk '{ print $1*0.000123981, $2 }'
```

I'm sure you can improve this to skip the header line and print it without modification.

You can also do this sort of thing with Perl, Python, C, Fortran, and many other languages, though it's unlikely to make much difference for such a simple calculation.

Comment: Did you removed my edit by intention? Otherwise, simply use `awk 'NR > 1 { print ... }` to skip the header line.

Comment: @hek2mgl No, I simply didn't see your edit before I made my own. But I did make an intentional decision not to include that in the code sample.

Comment: Uh, that's fine. That's why I was asking.. Btw, I doubt that a `C` program shows a significant performance advantage over awk, even if there are billions of lines. awk is *damn* fast!! :)

Comment: @hek2mgl I suppose that is true, since the bottleneck here is probably disk I/O rather than computation. (Now I've edited accordingly.)

Comment: Yep, that's true. Still, even if it gets more complicated, meaning parsing, splitting etc awk does an amazing job. Perl and Python are far from that and even a customized C solution is mostly not much faster. However, that depends on the problem, of course. Btw, really good answer! ;)

Comment: Great thanks! I knew this was was unoptimized as hell, just didn't know how. I'm sure it's apparent but I'm pretty new to this. Thanks for the pointers.

Comment: **Not true.** The biggest speedup, hands down, comes from not reading the entire input file multiple times in the main loop.  Based on a simple test file (just a single column of 2302 integers) the original script took 27 seconds, @chepner's answer (with just the single column) took 5 seconds, and this Awk script took 0.007 seconds.  But for a larger data set, where I/O will dominate the numbers, the factors will be much different. On 10,000 lines, the times are already 692, 25, and 0.014 seconds, respectively.  For scalability, fixing the algorithm will definitely be the key improvement.

Comment: (`while read -r` really is excruciatingly slow in this Bash; maybe I have a particularly broken version -- OSX Yosemite, Bash 3.2.57(1).)

Answer (score 4):

Your script runs 4603 separate `sed` processes, 4602 separate `awk` processes, and 2301 separate `bc` processes.  If `echo` were not a built-in then it would also run 2301 `echo` processes.  Starting a process has relatively large overhead.  Not so large that you would ordinarily notice it, but you are running over 11000 short processes.  The wall time consumption doesn't seem unreasonable for that.

**MOREOVER, each `sed` that you run processes the whole input file anew, selecting from it just one line.**  This is horribly inefficient.

The solution is to reduce the number of processes you are running, and especially to perform only a single run through the whole input file.  A fairly easy way to do that would be to convert to an `awk` script, possibly with a `bash` wrapper.  That might look something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

awk '
NR==1    { print; next }
NR>=2303 { exit }
         { print $1 * 0.000123981, $2 }
' data.txt > data_diff.txt
```

Note that the line beginning with `NR>=2303` artificially stops processing the input file when it reaches the 2303rd line, as your original script does; you could omit that line of the script altogether to let it simply process all the lines, however many there are.

Note, too, that that uses `awk`'s built-in FP arithmetic instead of running `bc`.  If you actually need the arbitrary-precision arithmetic of `bc` then I'm sure you can figure out how to modify the script to get that.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that sed processes was at least part of the problem. I wasn't aware that awk could multiply numbers either, I've really only ever used it to get columns. Thanks for your feedback, it's very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

As an example of how to speed up the `bash` script (without implying that this is the right solution)

```
#!/bin/bash

{ IFS= read -r header 
  echo "$header"
  # You can drop the third name "rest" if your input file
  # only has two columns.
  while read -r num sec rest; do
      nnum=$( bc <<< "$num * 0.000123981" )
      echo "$nnum $sec"
  done
} < data.txt > data_diff.txt
```

Now you only have one extra call to `bc` per data line, necessitated by the fact that `bash` doesn't do floating-point arithmetic. The right answer is to use a single call to program that *can* do floating-point arithmetic, as pointed out by David Z.

Comment: If you're going this route, you could optimize further by starting only one `bc` process and piping calculations to it as needed. `bc` evaluates line by line from standard input. Of course, the bash code would then get correspondingly more complicated.

Comment: Ugh. At that point, I use your `awk` solution :) I just wanted to point out that a lot, but not all, external processes can *easily* be replaced by in-shell constructs.